# $\sigma$- ideal

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, ideals

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space. $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is called a $\sigma$ ideal, if
> >     $$
> > (1)~\emptyset\in\mathcal{N},~~~~~(2) N\in\mathcal{N}, M\subset N\Rightarrow M\in\mathcal{N},~~~~~(3)(N_n)\in\mathcal{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\Rightarrow\bigcup_n N_n\in\mathcal{N}
> > $$
> >     Show that for every $\sigma$-ideal $\mathcal{N}$ it is
> >     $$
> > \sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})=\left\{A\Delta N|A\in\mathcal{A},N\in\mathcal{N}\right\}.
> > $$
> >     Hint: 
> >     $$
> > \left\{A\Delta N|A\in\mathcal{A},N\in\mathcal{N}\right\}=\left\{B\subset\Omega|\exists A\in\mathcal{A},N\in\mathcal{N}: B\setminus N=A\setminus N\right\}
> > $$

---

I do not have a special idea, to be honest.

For the inclusion "$\subseteq$ " I thought that maybe this is a strategy:

(1) Show that $\mathcal{S}:=\left\{A\Delta N|A\in\mathcal{A},N\in\mathcal{N}\right\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

(2) Show that $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}\in\mathcal{S}$.

Is that right or helpful? If yes: Which is the strategy for the other inclusion?

Comment: What is $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{N})$? What is $A\Delta N$?

Comment: $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$ is the $\sigma$-Algebra created by $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}$ and $A\Delta N=(A\setminus N)\cup (N\setminus A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strategy is a good one.

---

For the opposite direction, you want to show:

> If $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathcal A \cup \mathcal N$ implies $\mathcal S \subseteq \Sigma$.

(which is precisely saying that $\mathcal S$ fulfils the definition of generated $\sigma$-algebra).

In this case, I suggest to fix an element $A \Delta N \in \mathcal S$, and try to construct it from $\mathcal A \cup \mathcal N$ using the closure rules for a $\sigma$-algebra. (E.g. if $A_1,\ldots A_n \in \mathcal A$, then we know that $\bigcup_n A_n \in \Sigma$ for any $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ containing $\mathcal A$ -- this is the closure rule for "countable union").

Hint:

> $A \setminus N = A \cap N^\complement = (A^\complement \cup N)^\complement$

---

A hint for the union part of the initial direction (I assume you have either proved the hint given in the exercise or are allowed to use it without proof):

> \begin{align}\bigcup_n B_n \setminus \bigcup_m N_m&= \bigcup_n \left(B_n \setminus \left(\bigcup_m N_m\right)\right)\\&= \bigcup_n\left(\left(B_n \setminus N_n\right)\setminus \bigcup_{m \ne n} N_m\right)\\&= \bigcup_n \left(\left(A_n \setminus N_n\right)\setminus \bigcup_{m \ne n} N_m\right)\\&= \bigcup_n A_n \setminus \bigcup_m N_m\end{align}

I'll leave complement and containment of empty set to you.

Comment: To my calculation it is $\bigcup_n B_n\setminus\bigcup_m N_m=\bigcap_m((\bigcup_n B_n)\setminus N_m)$. I do not see that this is identical with $\bigcup_n(B_n\setminus (\bigcup_m N_m))$.

Comment: See [this ProofWiki page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_Difference_is_Right_Distributive_over_Union) for the result I used (well, the binary case thereof). $\bigcup_m N_m$ could've been any set.

Comment: Containment of complements: $B\in\mathcal{S}$, i.e. there exist a $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and a $N\in\mathcal{N}$ so that $B\setminus N=A\setminus N$. Then $B^C=\Omega\cap B^C=\Omega\cap ((B\setminus N)\cup N)^C=\Omega\cap ((A\setminus N)^C\cap N^C)=(\Omega\cap (A\setminus N)^C)\cap (\Omega\cap N^C)=(A\setminus N)^C\cap N^C=((A\setminus N)\cup N)^C=A^C$

Comment: So for $A^C\in\mathcal{A}$ and $N\in\mathcal{N}$ (which is the same $N$ that "belongs" to $B$) it is $B^C\setminus N=A^C\setminus N$ and therefore $B^C\in\mathcal{S}$. -- Am I right?

Comment: Hm, $B = B\setminus N \cup N$ holds iff $N \subseteq B$; but this might not be the case. This is not a big problem though. You can simply start with $B^c \setminus N$, use $(B\setminus N) \cup N = B \cup N$, and end with $A^c \setminus N$.

Comment: Thanks. And the containment of $\emptyset$: It is $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\emptyset\in\mathcal{N}$ and so $\emptyset\setminus N=A\setminus N$ for $A=N=\emptyset$.

Comment: So $\mathcal{S}$ is $\sigma$-Algebra. next step: I have to show that $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathcal{S}$ in order to get $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})\subseteq\mathcal{S}$, right? So consider $C\in\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}$, i.e. $C\in\mathcal{A}$ or $C\in\mathcal{N}$. If $C\in\mathcal{A}$ its, because of $\emptyset\in\mathcal{N}$, $C=C\Delta\emptyset$ and so $C\in\mathcal{S}$. If $C\in\mathcal{N}$ it is, because of $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}$, $C=\emptyset\Delta C$ and so again $C\in\mathcal{S}$. So it follows indeed $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})\subseteq\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Last step: Consider $A\Delta N\in\mathcal{S}$. Define $A':=A^C\cup N, N':=N\setminus A$. It's $A'\in\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$ and $N'\in\mathcal{N}, N'\in\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$. So $A'^C\in\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$. Because of $A\Delta N=A'^C\cup N'$ and finite unions of elements of $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$ are in $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$, it is $A\Delta N\in\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$. So $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})$. Is that right?

Comment: So if the last three comments are right, the proof is ready and it is shown that $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N})=\left\{A\Delta N| A\in\mathcal{A}, N\in\mathcal{N}\right\}$. - -

Comment: Looks fine to me (but I only gave it a cursory glance). Be sure to read it over once more when you've finished. Cheers!

Comment: One last question: How can I show, that $\left\{B\subset\Omega|\exists A\in\mathcal{A},N\in\mathcal{N}: B\setminus N=A\setminus N\right\}\subseteq\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: My idea: Consider a $C\in\left\{B\subset\Omega|\exists A\in\mathcal{A},N\in\mathcal{N}: B\setminus N=A\setminus N\right\}$. It is $C=(C\setminus N)\cup (C\cap N)=(A\setminus N)\cup (C\cap N)$. Now is there a possibility to write $(C\cap N)$ as $(N\setminus A)$?

Comment: $B = A \Delta(N \cap (A \Delta B))$. Draw a Venn diagram to see why this works.

Comment: Could you pls explain how you came to this identity? I would like to see how to get such ideas. :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11312/discussion-between-lord-farin-and-math12)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for $\subseteq$ this would be enough. (2) holds trivially, as $\emptyset\in\mathcal A\cap\mathcal N$, so that $A=A\Delta \emptyset\in\mathcal S$ and $N=\emptyset\Delta N\in\mathcal S$. 
For (1), observe that $A\Delta N=A\cup N'$ where $N'=N\setminus A \subseteq N$ so $N'\in\mathcal N$. Thus, we have
$$\bigcup_n(A_n\Delta N_n)=\bigcup_n(A_n\cup N_n') =\bigcup_nA_n\,\cup\,\bigcup_nN_n' =\bar A\cup\bar N\,,$$
where $\bar A=\bigcup_n A_n\in\mathcal A$ and $\bar N=\bigcup_n N_n'\in\mathcal N$.
Applying the same trick backwards, let $\bar N':=\bar N\setminus\bar A$, it is still in the $\sigma$-ideal $\mathcal N$. As $\bar N'$ and $\bar A$ are disjoint, we have
$$\bar A\cup\bar N=\bar A\cup\bar N'=\bar A\Delta\bar N'\,.$$
Similarly, $(A\Delta N)^\complement = (A\cup N')^\complement=A^\complement\cap (N')^\complement=A^\complement\setminus N'=A^\complement\Delta N''\ $ with $N'':=A^\complement\cap N'\ \in\mathcal N$.

And, for the other inclusion,

(3) Show that whenever a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal U$ contains $\mathcal A\cup\mathcal N$, it also contains $\mathcal S$.

Comment: Why is $A\Delta N=A\cup N'$ with $N'=N\setminus A$?