# Does $A \Delta N = A \cup N'$ in this proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ideals

Please have a look at this topic:
[$\sigma$- ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544702/sigma-ideal)

The answer says:

$A\Delta N=A\cup N'$ with $N'=N\setminus A$.

I do not see why this is correct..

Usually it is $A\Delta N=(A\setminus N)\cup (N\setminus A)$.

Unfortunately the helper does not answer and I really need a reason. I do not want to be impolite but i am in a hurry and need an answer to this little problem if possible.

Comment: Pls dont get me wrong! I asked this because it seems wrong to me and the whole proof build on this. Therefore for me it seems appropiate to ask this here again!

Comment: I think the tone of your question plays a big part in the downvotes. If you had formulated it in a way as to avoid the "this was posted in a rush" taste it leaves in one's mouth, it would've had a better reception. (Oh, and please don't ping users multiple times if they don't respond -- twice at most. Such is considered rude.)

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I am only a little bit frustrated, because I needed a hint to proof it and now wasted all my time with a wrong proof.

Comment: @math12 At the risk of sparking a bit of flame: _we are not here to do your homework for you_.  Getting help from a site like math.SE can be a good bonus, but it should never be an expectation, and no one likes to feel like their help is being *demanded*.  That you noticed the flaw in the previous effort is a point in your favor; but that should also give you most of what you need to correct any issues it might have created in that proof.

Comment: I am aware that you are not here to do it for me and I dont want that at all. Nevertheless for me its appropriate to ask if there is a mistake in a proof. I confess that I was to quick with this quation, sorry for that. Again, I say sorry if this appeared impolite! That was not my intention at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, it is a false, or at best unjustified, assertion.

It holds iff $A \setminus N = A$, i.e. $A \cap N =\varnothing$. But we don't know that.